# TFS Aumatically cancel check-out after a period of time

Tags: version-control, tfs

How to configure TFS to Aumatically cancel check-out after a period of time? (like 5 minute). This lock prevents other users from checking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn off the feature that locked the file on checkout. It's called exclusive check out and can be turned off in the source control properties of the team project in team explorer.

You can use gated builds to validate the code before checkin, both by a coder and on merge. If a gated build fails then checkin is not allowed. This you can add any checks that you like, time permitting, to the build to protect your code line. You can even, if you have at least one copy of Visual Studio ultimate, create a layer diagram and have it validated against your code. Simpler options include unit tests, style cop, static code analysis, and smoke tests.

Comment: The good part of this feature is that it helps prevent commits of Entity Framework code first migrations that brake the build. It's like a race condition between developers.

Comment: You can prevent this by configuring a gated checkin.

Comment: Does this solve the issue with migrations braking the build? And if so how?

Comment: What do you mean by migrations? I am not familiar with that terminology. Checkins are only committed if the build passes. Thus you can do any checked you like during the build.

Comment: Unit Tests are the only way to make sure that merged code does not have unintended side effects.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
Migrations are in the end classes that update the database base to a new version

Comment: I'll accept your answer for now, and post another question sometime soon to present the problem better. Thank you.